# using VolleyMultipartRequest for uploading all types of file but it's not work, is it possible to using Volley upload all type of file upload

Tags: java, android, android-volley, multipartform-data

```
public class VolleyMultipartRequest extends Request<NetworkResponse> {

private final String twoHyphens = "--";
private final String lineEnd = "\r\n";
private final String boundary = "apiclient-" + System.currentTimeMillis();

private Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> mListener;
private Response.ErrorListener mErrorListener;
private Map<String, String> mHeaders;


public VolleyMultipartRequest(int method, String url,
                              Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> listener,
                              Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, url, errorListener);
    this.mListener = listener;
    this.mErrorListener = errorListener;
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    return (mHeaders != null) ? mHeaders : super.getHeaders();
}

@Override
public String getBodyContentType() {
    return "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary;
}

@Override
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);

    try {
        // populate text payload
        Map<String, String> params = getParams();
        if (params != null && params.size() > 0) {
            textParse(dos, params, getParamsEncoding());
        }

        // populate data byte payload
        Map<String, DataPart> data = getByteData();
        if (data != null && data.size() > 0) {
            dataParse(dos, data);
        }

        // close multipart form data after text and file data
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        return bos.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Custom method handle data payload.
 *
 * @return Map data part label with data byte
 * @throws AuthFailureError
 */
protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() throws AuthFailureError {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected Response<NetworkResponse> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        return Response.success(
                response,
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    }
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    mListener.onResponse(response);
}

@Override
public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {
    mErrorListener.onErrorResponse(error);
}

/**
 * Parse string map into data output stream by key and value.
 *
 * @param dataOutputStream data output stream handle string parsing
 * @param params           string inputs collection
 * @param encoding         encode the inputs, default UTF-8
 * @throws IOException
 */
private void textParse(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, Map<String, String> params, String encoding) throws IOException {
    try {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
            buildTextPart(dataOutputStream, entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Encoding not supported: " + encoding, uee);
    }
}

/**
 * Parse data into data output stream.
 *
 * @param dataOutputStream data output stream handle file attachment
 * @param data             loop through data
 * @throws IOException
 */
private void dataParse(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, Map<String, DataPart> data) throws IOException {
    for (Map.Entry<String, DataPart> entry : data.entrySet()) {
        buildDataPart(dataOutputStream, entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
    }
}

/**
 * Write string data into header and data output stream.
 *
 * @param dataOutputStream data output stream handle string parsing
 * @param parameterName    name of input
 * @param parameterValue   value of input
 * @throws IOException
 */
private void buildTextPart(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, String parameterName, String parameterValue) throws IOException {
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + parameterName + "\"" + lineEnd);
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(parameterValue + lineEnd);
}

/**
 * Write data file into header and data output stream.
 *
 * @param dataOutputStream data output stream handle data parsing
 * @param dataFile         data byte as DataPart from collection
 * @param inputName        name of data input
 * @throws IOException
 */
private void buildDataPart(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, DataPart dataFile, String inputName) throws IOException {
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" +
            inputName + "\"; filename=\"" + dataFile.getFileName() + "\"" + lineEnd);
    if (dataFile.getType() != null && !dataFile.getType().trim().isEmpty()) {
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: " + dataFile.getType() + lineEnd);
    }
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

    ByteArrayInputStream fileInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(dataFile.getContent());
    int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

    int maxBufferSize = 1024 * 1024;
    int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

    while (bytesRead > 0) {
        dataOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }

    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
}

class DataPart {
    private String fileName;
    private byte[] content;
    private String type;

    public DataPart(String filePath, long pdfName, String selectedFilePath) {
    }

    DataPart(String name, byte[] data) {
        fileName = name;
        content = data;
    }

    String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    byte[] getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    String getType() {
        return type;
    }

}
```

}

i have try this code for upload all type of file on server this is not working but image is upload successfully, give error [443]

> NetworkDispatcher.processRequest: Unhandled exception
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array

Comment: Where this exception is thrown? Which part of your code is calling code that throws exception?

Comment: ByteArrayInputStream fileInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(dataFile.getContent());
        int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); this line

Comment: Is it possible that `dataFile` is empty? You are checking earlier if it is **not** empty, but don't do anything if it is...

Comment: but is working for image type

Comment: Did you debug this lines? Are you sure that all data is in proper form before line that causes exception? Debug it with file of another type then image.

Comment: yes this code is working for image upload but not working for all type file     params.put("params", new DataPart(selectedFilePath, imagename, "*/*"));

Comment: this code is for image  params.put("attach_files", new VolleyMultipartRequest.DataPart(imagename + ".jpg", getFileDataFromDrawable(bitmap)));